# rollup how to write a plugin that injects variables containing all imported IDs into the final source code?

Tags: rollup, rollupjs, rollup-plugin-babel

For example

```js
// entry.js
import allModules from 'virtual:all-modules';
import a from './a.js';

console.log(a);
```

```js
// a.js
import b from './b.js';
export default b;
```

```js
// b.js
export default {};
```

After rollup the `virtual:all-modules` will be `['entry.js', 'a.js', 'b.js']`.

I tried the `buildEnd` hooks, but it can't run `this.load({id: 'virtual:all-modules'})` again, the source code doesn't changed.